# Illegal invocation when trying to focus element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can somebody tell me why this throws an error when I click an input?

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [activeInput, setActiveInput] = React.useState()

  if (activeInput) activeInput.focus()

  return (
    <>
      <input onFocus={event => setActiveInput({focus: event.target.focus})}/>
      <input onFocus={event => setActiveInput({focus: event.currenTarget.focus})}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

### The use case

I have this tool where I can mark some text that is then pasted into the active input element. After a paste I want to refocus

Comment: You should look into [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: I'm not trying to be nosy, just to understand, why are you trying to refocus on focus?

Comment: I also don't see what this accomplishes. With this code you could only manually focus an already focused element.

Comment: I have this tool where I can mark some text that is then pasted into the active input element. After a paste I want to refocus

Comment: Ah, so its for re-focusing. Makes more sense.

Comment: you are not supposed to perform any side effects in render

Comment: is focusing considered a side effect? Not sure what the issue is @Max?

Comment: @mr.bjerre maybe if you can explain the use case of the component, that would help  us in trying to solve the problem. I'm failing to get what is supposed to happen with the inputs

Comment: of course, focusing is a side effect. In fact, everything except calculations that are needed for render is a side effect

Comment: Added use case. Cant see how I can eliminate the focus side effect for what I’m trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed I can do the following instead. Not sure why I can keep the element in a state but not the focus function.

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [activeInput, setActiveInput] = React.useState()

  if (activeInput) activeInput.el.focus()

  return (
    <>
      <input onFocus={event => setActiveInput({el: event.target})}/>
      <input onFocus={event => setActiveInput({el: event.currenTarget})}/>
    </>
  );
}
```